# Why was this question closed under company-specific regulations?

Tags: discussion

My [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/65407/coffee-maker-custody) was closed under the reasoning that:

> Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals

I'm sorry but I really disagree with this close reason, I don't see how it can be related to company policy. Some enlightenment from more experienced users or the ones who VTC would be greatly appreciated

If the question remains closed it's fine, since I already got my answer; but I would still like to understand the reasoning and perspective for closing it under this reason.

Comment: Please re-read the reason it was closed. I'd say that this is a company-specific (internal) ***agreement***. As such, it's not something we can help with.

Answer (score 2):

Reason for Closure:

> Questions seeking **advice on company-specific** regulations, **agreements**, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department.

Where the reason applies:

> We agreed as departments to pitch in for the supplies

And the reason *why* it should be closed:

> Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors.

It could also be closed under "*Primarily opinion based*"  as well as "*Questions asking for advice on what to do are not practical answerable questions*"